# Render markup string correctly in React

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a quite small problem, but little blocker now. I am using Hygraph CMS with React/Next JS front and most of the cases like this `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` or `import parse from 'html-react-parser'` should render fine but not now.

The problem is any kind of a html tags which edit text style not work. Like `<b>`, `<strong>`, `em` and `u`.

Both of the examples I tried render the text without style.

Example, this string `<p><strong>Error</strong> <em>in</em> system</p>`  is rendered like this `Error in system` and it should render like this **Error** *in* system.

Example of use:

```
import parse from 'html-react-parser'

<ul>
  <li>{notiFicationData.text.html}</li>
  <li dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: notiFicationData.text.html }} />
  <li>{parse(notiFicationData.text.html)}</li>
</ul>
```

Look like this, here you can see the string as it comes from the Hygraph:

[image]
Any idea why it is not rendering bold and other text visual tags?

Comment: Can you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Undo I created some updates to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Not with the best way but this is not efficient to wrestling too much with this kind of a problem.

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` works exactly as it should. Somewhere in app is overwrite for strong, italic and other HTML text tags. Found from inspector computed tab that strong font-weight is computed as value 400. I couldn't find a place where this is overwrited. So I created styled computed for that where I overwrite these:

```
const NotificationText = styled.div`
  strong {
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  em {
    font-style: italic;
  }
  u {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
`

<NotificationText dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: notificationData.text.html }} />
```

Now it looks nice :)

[image]